# Checking Inheritance with templates in C++

Tags: java, c++, templates

I've a class which is a wrapper class(serves as a common interface) around another class implementing the functionality required. So my code looks like this.

```
template<typename ImplemenationClass> class WrapperClass {
// the code goes here
}
```

Now, how do I make sure that `ImplementationClass` can be derived from a set of classes only, similar to java's generics

```
<? extends BaseClass>
```

syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's verbose, but you can do it like this:

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>

struct base {};

template <typename ImplementationClass, class Enable = void>
class WrapperClass;

template <typename ImplementationClass>
class WrapperClass<ImplementationClass,
      typename boost::enable_if<
        boost::is_base_of<base,ImplementationClass> >::type>
{};

struct derived : base {};
struct not_derived {};

int main() {
    WrapperClass<derived> x;

    // Compile error here:
    WrapperClass<not_derived> y;
}
```

This requires a compiler with good support for the standard (most recent compilers should be fine but old versions of Visual C++ won't be). For more information, see the [Boost.Enable_If documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

As Ferruccio said, a simpler but less powerful implementation:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>

struct base {};

template <typename ImplementationClass>
class WrapperClass
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((
        boost::is_base_of<base, ImplementationClass>::value));
};
```

Comment: You can make it a little clearer by using BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT in place of enable_if. i.e.

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_base_of<base,ImplementationClass>);

Comment: Yep, I've added that. I prefer enable_if as it lets you have different versions and gives slightly better error messages (IMO). Some people also like the error messages from MPL's static assert.

Answer (score 2):

In the current state of things, there is no good way other than by comments or a third-party solution. Boost provides a [concept check library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) for this, and I think gcc also has an implementation. Concepts are on the list of C++0x improvements, but I'm not sure if you can specify subtypes - they are more for "must support these operations" which is (roughly) equivalent.

**Edit:** Wikipedia has this [section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Concepts) about concepts in C++0x, which is significantly easier to read than draft proposals.

Answer (score 0):

See [Stoustrup's own words on the subject](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#constraints).

Basically a small class, that you instantiate somewhere, e.g. the templated classes constructor.

```
template<class T, class B> struct Derived_from {
    static void constraints(T* p) { B* pb = p; }
    Derived_from() { void(*p)(T*) = constraints; }
};
```